# What is a Dial Word™?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Dial Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Dial Words™ | Not Dial Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| TAX | DUES |
| MUD | DUST |
| PAR | EAGLE |
| DEAF | DUMB |
| ONLY | ONE |
| KITE | SAIL |
| QUITS | LEAVES |
| GLAZE | SHINE |
| WINDOW | DOOR |
| WINDOWS | LINUX |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Dial Words™,Not Dial Words™
TAX,DUES
MUD,DUST
PAR,EAGLE
DEAF,DUMB
ONLY,ONE
KITE,SAIL
QUITS,LEAVES
GLAZE,SHINE
WINDOW,DOOR
WINDOWS,LINUX
```

Comment: Duplicate of [What is an Indivisible Word™?](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/60247)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that a Dial Word satisfies the property that

> If we convert the letters of the word to numbers using the mappings of a [telephone keypad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_keypad) we obtain a prime number

Examples

> TAX $\rightarrow$ 829, which is prime
>  WINDOW $\rightarrow$ 946369, which is prime.
>  WINDOWS $\rightarrow$ 9463697, which is prime.

Comment: You got it~~~:D